# Arduino (TinyGPS) - por que gps.encode retorna sempre false?

Tags: arduino, gps

Estou fazendo uns testes com o arduino UNO e o módulo gps NEO6MV2. É um componente bem popula, mas tenho dois módulos com o mesmo problema:

Ao rodar o código a lib TinyGPS não consegue traduzir nada que venha da entrada:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial pins(10, 11);
TinyGPSPlus gps;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pins.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if(pins.available()) {
    Serial.println("pins ok!");
    if(gps.encode(pins.read())) { // false ever
      Serial.println(gps.altitude.meters());       
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("pins not ready...");
  }
  delay(1000);
}
```

[image: monitor]